# Code Analysis Warning about Disposing a Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I have a couple of static methods which convert a Form to a Control (shown below). The analyzer flags both, stating, "CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method '...', object 'form' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'form' before all references to it are out of scope." Similar is flagged for `tabPage`.

NOTE: for those who don't have Enterprise Edition and the Analyzer menu, this looks a lot like FxCop output.

I'm not clear on what I should be doing. If `new` fails, an exception will be thrown. Where is my opportunity to call `Dispose`?

```
class Foo
{
  static public Form FormAsControl()
  {
    Form form = new Foo();

    form.TopLevel = false;
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.Visible = true;

    return form;
  }

  static public TabPage FormAsTabPage()
  {
    Form form = Foo.FormAsControl();
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();

    tabPage.Text = form.Text;
    tabPage.Controls.Add(form);

    return tabPage;
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CA2000 is troublesome, too many false warnings.  FxCop isn't smart enough to know how the Control class works.  Its Dispose() method only does something useful *after* the native control window gets created.  Only then will there be unmanaged resources that could be disposed.  But that won't happen until the TabPage you return gets added to a TabControl and that control in turn is added to a form and the Show() method of that form is called.  Code we cannot see (nor FxCop for that matter).  Furthermore, they actually *do* get disposed, even when there's an exception, when the native window gets destroyed.

You could suppress the warning by adding try/catch to the methods so you can call Dispose() in the catch block.  But that would be a mistake, it just adds unnecessary code that doesn't do anything useful at runtime.  Use the [SuppressMessage] attribute to get rid of the warning.

Comment: "[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2000")]" worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, not only *should* you ignore the warning, but you *must* ignore the warning.

A naive implementation might be

```
public Control FormAsControl()
{
    using (Form form = new Foo())
    {
        // Set properties
        return form;
    }
}
```

but then `form` will have been disposed before the caller can use it!

Note that I'm assuming you meant class `Foo` to derive from `Form`, and that you meant `FormAsControl` to return `Control`, not `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you should be able to safely ignore that warning.

Answer (score 1):

We can learn something from C++'s RAII techniques here:

```
class auto_disposer<C> : IDisposable where C : class
{
    public C Child { get; private set; }
    public auto_disposer(C c) { Child = c; }

    public void Dispose() { IDisposable d =  Child as IDisposable; if (d != null) d.Dispose(); }
    public C Release() { C retval = Child; Child = null; return retval; }
}

class Foo
{
     static public Form FormAsControl()
     {
         using (var ad = new auto_disposer<Foo>(new Foo())) {
             Form form = ad.Child;
             form.TopLevel = false;
             form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
             form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
             form.Visible = true;

             return ad.Release();
         }
     }

     // ...
}
```

This way, **if any property assignments cause an exception**, the object is still properly disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception, call Dispose, throw?